# Window Switcher messed up

Tags: unity, window, unity-tweak-tool

I was messing around with Unity Tweak Tool and Unity crashed. And then I end up with this mess for Alt+Tab
[image: My messed-up alt+tab]

I tried `unity --replace` and `unity --reset`, but both didn't work. How do I fix this?

Comment: I have the same on my laptop on which I installed Ubuntu 16.04.5 amd64 freshly yesterday...

Answer (score 4):

Looks like it's a conflict with Compiz's window switcher. What I did to fix this problem was installing `compizconfig-settings-manager`.

When installed, launch the app, pick "Window Management" from the Category panel, and uncheck Application Switcher. Now Alt+Tab is handled only by Unity's window switcher.